# Double free error on fclose() on previously closed file handle

Tags: c++, file-io, null

I have a class that contains file handle `fHandle` that points to an open file. Now, it can be closed by any one of the multiple routines and that is based on dynamic run of the program.

To be sure that a file is indeed closed, I put simple snippet in my destructor: `if(fHandle!=NULL) fclose(fHandle);`. Turns out, if one of the routines had previously closed this file, then the running the destructor snippet causes double free operation and I get `**glib detected**` error message.

How do I make sure that I don't close the file handle that has previously been closed (apart from putting `NULL` check)?

Comment: If you use classes aka C++ you should tag it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you've tried:

```
if(fHandle!=NULL) fclose(fHandle);
```

To avoid a double `fclose()`, just set `fHandle` to `NULL` whereever else you may call `fclose` on that handle, so the above code in the destructor won't pass the conditional test....

Answer (score 1):

fclose doesn't set the fhandle to NULL. So, after calling fclose if you set the fhandle to NULL explicity it should solve your problem.

Your code should be something like below:

```
if(NULL != fhandle)
{
   fclose(fhandle);
   fhandle = NULL;
}
```

Note: This solution will not work if your function that calls close is called from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Is this specifically C or C++. One easy fix for your latter issue to use a seperate flag to check if the file is closed or not? Something like this

```
void CloseFile(){
  if(flag ==0){
    fclose(fHandle);
      flag =1;
  }
}
```

If this is for c++ you can encapsulate the file handle inside a class and use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to automatically call the close just once by adding that call in the class's destructor. You could also (not recommended) not do RAII and merely encapsulate the flag within the same class if you want to go that way, and call `close` manually.