# Fclose a file that is already fclose

Tags: c++, c, fclose

In my programm I may close a file that is already close. What happen when I do a `fclose` on a file already close ?

And if you can't do so, how to know if a file is closed or open ?

Comment: Seems like a number of those results answer your question.

Comment: No ... But thanks for the down vote ... Can't ask a question on this site :(

Comment: I looked through the results, and it seems like they answer your question as stated. [What happens to FILE pointer after file is closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441059/what-happens-to-file-pointer-after-file-is-closed), [Double free error on fclose() on previously closed file handle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811464/double-free-error-on-fclose-on-previously-closed-file-handle)

Comment: Try it and see... However: if `fopen` fails, the `FILE *` is set to `NULL`, that's how you can tell if a `FILE *` is set or not. Just set it to `NULL` after `fclose` if you want to play it extra-safe

Comment: @crashmstr seems a little different to me - this asks what should happen when you call fclose twice - that question says "hey, my particular library implementation logs some crap I don't want" - which generally shouldn't be the case - and asks for a workaround.  Of course, Evans might be unlucky enough to have the same implementation/problem, but that's not established.

Comment: Not clear why this was downvoted, I could not find an older duplcate of  this question.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour This is the 1st result I found from Google also. Maybe it's fundamental knowledge to someone, but to me, it's totally valuable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Calling `fclose` twice with the same stream is undefined behaviour - most likely crash. There is no way to check if `FILE*` has been closed already, so the safe solution is to set pointer to NULL as soon as it is closed:

```
fclose(fh);
fh = NULL;
```

Sources: "The value of a pointer to a FILE object is indeterminate after the associated file is closed" (C draft standard). "After the call to fclose(), any use of stream causes undefined behaviour." (The Single UNIX ® Specification).

Comment: The standard does not seem to apply to the case of a call to fclose with NULL, so it is an undefined behavior that can also lead to crash