# Undefined behavior fopen, fclose

Tags: c++, c, file, fopen, fclose

Can the following code result in undefined behavior?

```
FILE *fp;
fopen_s(&fp, "abc.bin", "rb");
fclose(fp);
fclose(fp); // accidentally closed an already closed file.
```

I know that calling free on an already freed up array results in UB. Hence I ask.

Comment: It's undefined behavior of course.

Comment: In a complex situation that is hard to keep track of, just as with `free()` if you set the pointer to `NULL` at the point of declaration, and after closing or freeing, you can then check it before the `fclose()` or `free()` call to save a lot of grief.

Comment: @WeatherVane: But unfortunately, in difference to `free`, it is not well defined to call `fclose` with a `NULL` pointer. I would suggest "checking" for `NULL` before `free` is a bad thing. Checking for `NULL` before calling `fclose` is definitely a good thing.

Comment: Also see [Fclose a file that is already fclose](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24555980/1708801) looks like a duplicate

Comment: @MatsPetersson How about `if (!nullptr == fp)
   fclose(fp); ` ?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I didn't say to call `fclose(NULL)` or `free(NULL)`. I said it allows you to check the pointer status and ***not*** call those functions. but with a file, you need to be careful to distinguish that a file handle can be `0`.

Comment: Right, and my point is that `free`, since about 1990 [or before], tolerates calls with a `NULL` pointer - so you should NOT check for `NULL` before calling `free` (because it's extra code that doesn't do anything meaningful), but you should before calling `fclose`. Which is rather confusing. Better to avoid both and use `fstream`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I don't understand your quibble. Is my suggestion that you set a freed memory pointer, or a closed file pointer to `NULL` wrong, so that in the first case it is benign to `free()`, and in the second, checkable to `fclose()`?

Comment: No, but your suggestion to "check for `NULL` before calling `free` leads to extra code for no good reason, wheras you NEED to do that in the case of `fclose`.

Comment: That's what I originally said. Check for `NULL`, sorry I mentioned `free()` now, but you went right off topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from `man fclose`:

> The  behaviour  of  fclose()  is  undefined  if  the  stream  parameter is an illegal pointer, or is a descriptor already passed to a previous invocation of fclose().

So yes, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: POSIX also says it's UB: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fclose.html

Comment: Agreed.  An implementation could always `new/malloc` the `FILE` in `fopen(_s)()` and `delete/free` it in `fclose()`,or it could use a private cache, and both would be legal.  The caller should not make any assumptions about the validity of a `FILE*` pointer after passing it to `fclose()`, just NULL it and move it.

Comment: Why does it say *stream parameter*? Not using streams here

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: ISO C11 Draft N1570, 7.21.3 par. 4: `The value of a pointer to a FILE object is indeterminate after the associated file is closed (including the standard text streams).`