# fwrite function causes exception when running in wine

Tags: c, linux, wine

The following C code compiled under windows caused an exception under linux(wine).

The code is simply writing something into a file, works fine under Windows. And the code did not use any graphic API, but wine warned about creating a window.

The text is actually written to the file correctly, but the program crashed.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp;
int main(){
    if( fp = fopen("Write.txt", "w") ){
        if (fp){
            fwrite("WineTest\n", 1, 9, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            fp = NULL;
        }
        else printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error info:

```
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000050 at address 0x7bc49308 (thread 005f), starting debugger... err:winediag:nulldrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded. err:winediag:nulldrv_CreateWindow Make sure that your X server is running and that $DISPLAY is set correctly. Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000050 in 64-bit code (0x000000007bc49308). Register dump:  rip:000000007bc49308 rsp:000000000033fbc0 rbp:000000000033fc50 eflags:00010206 (  R- --  I 
- -P- )  rax:00007f48dacafe40 rbx:0000000000000030 rcx:0000000000000030 rdx:00007f48dacb13a0  rsi:0000000000000019 rdi:0000000000010620  r8:00000000004300e8  r9:0000000000540000 r10:0000000000000008  r11:0000000000000246 r12:0000000000000001 r13:0000000000000008 r14:00007f48dc70e608 r15:0000000000000019 Stack dump: 0x000000000033fbc0:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x000000000033fbd0:  00007f48dacafed0 0000000000000000 0x000000000033fbe0:  0000000000000000 00007f48daa2a45e 0x000000000033fbf0:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x000000000033fc00:  0000000000000001 0000000000000008 0x000000000033fc10:  0000000000000001 0000000000000001 0x000000000033fc20:  0000000000000019 00000000004015cc 0x000000000033fc30:  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0x000000000033fc40:  0000000000000000 0000000000000001 0x000000000033fc50:  0000000000431910 00000000004013e8 0x000000000033fc60:  00004d338ffde2c3 00002b992ddfa232 0x000000000033fc70:  00000000f9f27ba5 000000000000005f Backtrace:
=>0 0x000000007bc49308 RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x8() in ntdll (0x000000000033fc50)   1 0x00007f48daa2a45e MSVCRT_fclose+0xd() in msvcrt (0x000000000033fc50)   2 0x00000000004015cc in winetest (+0x15cb) (0x000000000033fc50)   3 0x00000000004013e8 in winetest (+0x13e7) (0x0000000000431910)   4 0x000000000040151b in winetest (+0x151a) (0x00007fffff7ef000)   5 0x000000007b47937b in kernel32 (+0x5937a) (0x00007fffff7ef000)   6 0x000000007bc964be call_thread_func+0xcd() in ntdll (0x00007fff73b1b600)   7 0x000000007bc8f552 RtlRaiseException+0x7d() in ntdll (0x00007fff73b1b600)   8 0x000000007bc5eca0 in ntdll (+0x3ec9f) (0x00007fff73b1b600)   9 0x00007f48dc372843 wine_call_on_stack+0x12() in libwine.so.1 (0x00007fff73b1b600)   10 0x00007f48dc3729a9 wine_switch_to_stack+0x8() in libwine.so.1 (0x00007fffff7ef000)   11 0x000000007bc65210 LdrInitializeThunk+0x30f() in ntdll (0x00007fffff7ef000)   12 0x000000007b47fa78
__wine_kernel_init+0x9f7() in kernel32 (0x00007fff73b1baa0)   13 0x000000007bc661e8 __wine_process_init+0x167() in ntdll (0x00007fff73b1c7c0)   14 0x00007f48dc37149e wine_init+0x29d() in libwine.so.1 (0x00007fff73b1c8a0)   15 0x000000007c000b12 main+0x71() in <wine-loader> (0x00007fff73b1cd98)   16 0x00007f48dbdb1b45
__libc_start_main+0xf4() in libc.so.6 (0x0000000000000000)   17 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 18 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   19 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   20 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   21 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 22 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   23 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   24 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   25 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 26 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   27 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   28 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   29 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 30 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   31 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   32 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   33 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 34 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   35 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   36 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   37 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 38 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   39 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   40 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   41 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 42 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   43 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   44 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   45 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 46 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   47 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   48 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   49 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 50 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   51 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   52 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   53 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 54 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   55 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   56 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   57 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 58 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   59 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   60 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   61 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 62 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   63 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   64 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   65 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 66 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   67 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   68 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   69 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 70 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   71 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   72 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   73 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 74 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   75 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   76 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   77 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 78 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   79 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   80 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   81 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 82 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   83 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   84 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   85 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 86 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   87 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   88 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   89 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 90 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   91 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   92 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   93 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 94 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   95 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   96 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   97 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 98 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   99 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   100 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   101 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 102 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   103 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   104 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   105 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 106 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   107 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   108 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   109 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 110 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   111 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   112 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   113 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 114 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   115 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   116 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   117 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 118 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   119 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   120 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   121 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 122 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   123 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   124 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   125 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 126 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   127 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   128 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   129 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 130 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   131 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   132 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   133 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 134 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   135 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   136 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   137 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 138 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   139 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   140 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   141 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 142 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   143 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   144 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   145 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 146 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   147 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   148 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   149 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 150 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   151 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   152 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   153 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 154 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   155 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   156 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   157 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 158 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   159 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   160 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   161 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 162 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   163 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   164 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   165 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 166 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   167 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   168 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   169 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 170 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   171 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   172 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   173 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 174 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   175 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   176 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   177 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 178 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   179 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   180 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   181 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 182 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   183 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   184 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   185 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 186 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   187 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   188 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   189 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 190 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   191 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   192 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   193 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 194 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   195 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   196 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   197 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 198 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   199 0x000000007c000c0a _start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000)   200 0x000000007c000c0a
_start+0x28() in <wine-loader> (0x0000000000000000) 0x000000007bc49308 RtlEnterCriticalSection+0x8 in ntdll: cmpq   $0,0x0000000000000020(%rcx) Modules: Module  Address                   Debug info      Name (22 modules) PE                400000-          422000       Dwarf           winetest ELF             7b400000-        7b804000       Dwarf           kernel32<elf>   \-PE          7b420000- 7b804000       \               kernel32 ELF             7bc00000-      7bd13000       Dwarf           ntdll<elf>   \-PE          7bc20000-    7bd13000       \               ntdll ELF             7c000000-        7c002000       Dwarf           <wine-loader> ELF         7f48da589000- 7f48da7b3000       Deferred        libtinfo.so.5 ELF         7f48da7b3000-    7f48da9d8000       Deferred        libncurses.so.5 ELF         7f48da9d8000-    7f48dacb2000       Dwarf           msvcrt<elf>   \-PE      7f48daa00000-    7f48dacb2000       \          msvcrt ELF         7f48dae3b000-    7f48db047000       Deferred        libnss_files.so.2 ELF         7f48db047000-    7f48db252000       Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2 ELF         7f48db252000-    7f48db46a000       Deferred        libnsl.so.1 ELF         7f48db46a000-    7f48db672000       Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2 ELF         7f48db672000-    7f48db888000       Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1 ELF         7f48db888000-    7f48dbb89000       Deferred libm.so.6 ELF         7f48dbb8c000-    7f48dbd90000       Deferred     libdl.so.2 ELF         7f48dbd90000-    7f48dc13b000       Dwarf       libc.so.6 ELF         7f48dc13c000-    7f48dc359000       Deferred     libpthread.so.0 ELF         7f48dc369000-    7f48dc70f000       Dwarf  libwine.so.1 ELF         7f48dc711000-    7f48dc934000       Deferred  ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ELF         7fff73b34000-    7fff73b36000       Deferred        [vdso].so Threads: process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex) 0000000e services.exe
        00000020    0
        0000001f    0
        00000014    0
        00000010    0
        0000000f    0 00000012 winedevice.exe
        0000001e    0
        00000019    0
        00000018    0
        00000013    0 0000001c plugplay.exe
        00000022    0
        00000021    0
        0000001d    0 00000023 explorer.exe
        00000027    0
        00000026    0
        00000025    0
        00000024    0 00000036 wineconsole.exe
        0000003a    0
        00000037    0 00000038 Cam_1.exe
        0000003c    0
        0000003b    0
        00000039    0 0000003e wineconsole.exe
        00000042    0
        0000003f    0 00000040 Cam_2.exe
        00000044    0
        00000043    0
        00000041    0 0000005e (D) Z:\home\jwz\WineTest.exe
        0000005f    0 <== System information:
    Wine build: wine-2.0.2
    Platform: x86_64
    Version: Windows XP
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
```

Compile system: Windows 7 x64

Compiler: MinGW g++

Linux: Debian 8 x64

Wine: wine/wineconsole/wine64 (tried all the three, same error)

Comment: why are you closing it twice ?

Comment: And why are you testing twice if `fp` is different to `NULL`?. The first test `if( fp = fopen("Write.txt", "w") ){` does already test if `fp` is `NULL`.

Comment: You really don't want to call `fclose(fp)` just after `fp = NULL` - that's Undefined Behaviour, and you were simply unlucky that it didn't segfault on your Windows host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing twice if the open succeds !
I commented the second fclose(fp).
Please check:
[Fclose a file that is already fclose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555980/fclose-a-file-that-is-already-fclose)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *fp;
int main(){
    if( fp = fopen("Write.txt", "w") ){
        if (fp){
            fwrite("WineTest\n", 1, 9, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            fp = NULL;
        }
        else printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        //fclose(fp); EDIT:Commented
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not quite - it closes `fp`, then it closes `NULL`.  That's arguably worse.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (fp){
    fwrite("WineTest\n", 1, 9, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = NULL;
}
else printf("Cannot open file.\n");
fclose(fp);
```

The second call to `fclose` always passes a NULL pointer.